# HTML5 Camera access not working in Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, microsoft-edge

I've used this code ([reference to source code](http://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera)) where I try to show a stream of video for the user and allow him to take a snapshot, this is working fine on Chrome for example but does not work on Microsoft Edge at all and no errors are shown. Any idea why this is not working and maybe reference a different approach I should take?
I'm pretty sure it does not work on Safari either...

Even the [Microsoft's Demo page](http://dev.modern.ie/testdrive/demos/photocapture/) is not working! here is a screenshot of the error I get:
[image]

And my device manager:
[image]

EDIT (3 Sep 15): I have turned on "Let apps use my Camera" in my Windows Settings and now this demo works well on all browsers **but** Safari. Anyone know what is the best approach to capturing an image from a webcam stream in Safari?

Comment: [`navigator.getUserMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUser#MediaBrowser_compatibility) is not supported in IE nor in Safari. The new version, [mediaDevices.getUserMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) is currently only supported in FF

Comment: It is supported in Edge though. So my question is this, is there an alternative I can use?

Comment: according to [this blog post](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/05/13/announcing-media-capture-functionality-in-microsoft-edge/), IE Edge will support `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`, you are using `navigator.getUserMedia()`. The other alternatives for this are flash and java.

Comment: @Kaiido hey, thanks man, that's really helpful! :)

Comment: Actually, I have found a demo microsoft made to show the new mediaDevices you mentioned: http://dev.modern.ie/testdrive/demos/photocapture/
I try it on Edge and I get an error: ERROR: Webcam not found.
I have installed my webcam drivers again just to make sure it is working well. Ideas?

Comment: I don't have edge to test out, but try this with FF, if it works there, then IE is bugged (They just started the implementation and call it a "preview_release", so bugs are expected), contact them, fill a bug report.

Comment: Roger that, thanks again mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the Photo Capture using webcam demo on Edge and it is working quite fine. you can check the below screenshot.
You need to use `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`. Even though Chrome 45 has `navigator.mediaDevices` and a `getUserMedia` function which returns a Promise, it does not accept spec-style constraints.

> Note: Make sure to turn on the Camera setting "Let apps use my
>   camera" and from the list of apps that can use your camera turn on Microsoft Edge as well.

[image]

Comment: Well Rami, I have tried that demo page on microsoft's website using Microsoft Edge browser on 2 different computers, it didn't work, it couldn't recognize my camera. I'll post a screenshot tomorrow.

Comment: Check out my revised question fpr the screenshots I promised, one shows that the demo doesn't work in Edge and the other shows my device manager, Lenovo EasyCamera is installed just fine.

Comment: @odedta did you tried it with a different browser (FF) so you are sure your device works properly?

Comment: Indeed I have, it is a bug with Microsoft Edge browser :/ I am on Lenovo Y50

Comment: yes, in this case file a bug. in the meantime, do you see any errors in the console (F12 develope tools) ?

Comment: Actually, I just read some articles about this error and it seems that I turned off a settings in the camera, "Let apps use my camera"
Hehe, things you just never know I guess :/

Comment: So, my test is working on all browsers except Safari. What's the best approach to capture an image from a video in Safari?

Comment: yes of course you need to allow Edge to use your camera :) Edge is an app at the end of the day. so things are working on Edge now ? I will add this note to my answer.

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Could not start video source in EDGE, version 99.0.1150.46, 64 bits.

Answer (score 3):

You need to open Privacy Settings. Enable Camera and Microphone for Edge, otherwise you will get a permission error.

Answer (score 0):

for me #Michael Wanyoike hit it on the head. You have to enable camera permissions. The weird thing is that no prompt requesting permission appeared, simply a black screen. It could be that previously I had click deny but still not a smooth flow.